# How to solve Error 400 on html page post method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have make a simple html file to get my data and add button to post data but however i am returning error 400

My get method are running fine with displaying the backend data out in the html but however post method i am returning some errors 400 due to my query which i not sure why is there any way i can prevent this error 400 ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add recycables</title>
        <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "add"></div>
        <P>Add recycables</P>
        <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
        <p>type:<input type="text" id="type"> </p>
        <button id="add">Add</button>
    </body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $items = $('#add');
            var $name = $('#name');
            var $type = $('#type');
            $.ajax({
                                    
                                    url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",
                                
                                    method:"GET",
                                    // In this case, we are going to use headers as
                                    headers:{
                                        // The query you're planning to call
                                        // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                                        query:"RecyclableGet(0)",
                                        
                                        // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                        apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                                    },

                                    

                                    success:function(data, item, xhr,textStatus) {
                                    //console.log(data) 
                                    
                                    $.each(data, function(i, item){
                                        $items.append('<li>name: '+item.Name +', type: '+ item.RecyclableType + '</li>');
                                    });

                                  
                                    },

                                    error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    });





                                    $('#add').on('click', function(){
                                        var addRecyclables = {
                                            Name: $name.val,
                                            RecyclableType: $type.val
                                        }
                                    })
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url:"https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/post",
                                        method:"POST",
                                        headers:{
                                        // The query you're planning to call
                                        // i.e. <query> can be UserGet(0), RecyclableGet(0), etc.
                                            query:`RecyclableAdd('${name}','${type}')`,
                                        
                                        // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                                        apikey:sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                                    },
                                    success:function(data, Newitem, xhr,textStatus){
                                        $items.append('<li>name: '+Newitem.Name +', type: '+ Newitem.RecyclableType + '</li>');

                                    },
                                    error:function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Json file look like
[image: image of how json file]

my html on web
[image: 400 error]

Comment: This likely means you are using the API incorrectly. [Error `400` means bad request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400), so check the website's documentation, alter your code, and try again. It's probably because the API only supports `GET` requests but not `POST` requests. They're pretty different, you know?

Comment: yea but i already change my api to post to match my json
https://imgur.com/5p7VMyI

Comment: In `error` in jQuery AJAX, trying `console.log`ging the text status. That might tell you something.